# Sklearn LocalOutlierFactor contamination parameter

Tags: scikit-learn

Can anyone provide an intuitive explanation of the choice of `contamination` parameter used in sklearn's LocalOutlierFactor implementation when `contamination="auto"` ?

The sklearn guide suggests "as described in the paper" but I couldn't find anything obvious. Thanks.

Comment: I second this question, and none of the answers below really address it... Did you find an answer to this @sandyp?

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying with a floating point number what proportion of the data you are fitting on is an outlier. If you use 'Auto' it will default to 0.1. Note that in the current documentation, there is a changed note specifying that it will default to 0.2 in a future version.

Comment: In the current documentation, it says it will default to whatever is in the paper. I couldn't find it in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

(this answer assumes you were asking about how the `offset_` attribute was chosen when `contamination="auto"`)

The only place in the paper that I can conceive of that factor coming from is [Section 7.3](https://www.dbs.ifi.lmu.de/Publikationen/Papers/LOF.pdf), where the original authors explored soccer data and say

> Below we
>   discuss all the local outliers with LOF > 1.5 (see table 3), and explain why they are exceptional.